# When are upvoted answers listed above accepted answers?

Tags: support, voting, accepted-answer

Occasionally on AskUbuntu, I've seen highly upvoted answers listed before the accepted answer for a question. This is useful for when the OP accepts a suboptimal or incorrect answer.

However, when does this phenomenon occur? For [some questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95336/why-cant-i-update-applications-without-upgrading-the-whole-os/) it clearly doesn't. Is there a mathematical ratio of upvotes vs. downvotes? If so, what is the ratio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The highest voted answer is listed first if the accepted answer is made by the OP. See [Why are the accepted answers always on the top of the answer list?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2318/why-are-the-accepted-answers-always-on-the-top-of-the-answer-list) for details.

Note that you can choose how to sort answers. Currently it is possible to sort by activity, date and votes. The latter is the default.